# She’d come off her new bike and hurt her knee. (she'd)

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, verb-usage

> She’d come off her new bike

> **and hurt her knee.**

before you see **and hurt her knee.**

What was the intrepretation of 'she'd' when you (as native English speakers) first read the sentence above?

1. she would
2. she had

Comment: If the context is "hypothetical", then ***IF*** that hypothetical context were to be true, it's #1 ***She'd** / She **would** fall off and [would] hurt herself.* On the other hand, if the context is simply explaining how she came to be injured (at some contextually-relevant time that's *already* in the past), it's Past Perfect #2 *She **had** fallen and [had] hurt herself*. But note that we rarely bother repeating the Perfect verb form in case #2 - once is enough to establish that the accident happened ***before*** some time in the past that we're currently talking about.

Comment: ...That's to say, the Past Perfect version requires some pre-existing "past" context. For example, ***When I saw her last month**, she’d (she **had**) fallen off and hurt herself*.

Comment: Thx. FumbleFingers. What did you mean in "But note that we rarely bother repeating the Perfect verb form in case #2". There is only one 'had' in "had pp"

Comment: I meant that *syntactically* it's perfectly okay to say *She’d* (or *She **had***) *come off her new bike and **had** hurt her knee*, but *in practice* we wouldn't usually repeat the Perfect form in such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And if you're describing a recurring situation/habit/state of affairs in the past "She'd come off here bike..." would be interpreted as as a repeated or habitual occurrence.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: You'd think she'd learn to ride better before it became a "habitual action" - but *in principle*, yeah! :)

Answer (score 8):

Could be either.

This is like asking if "The wood..." is understood to mean "the forest" or the "the timber".  It can only be resolved by context.  If you explicitly remove that context, it must be ambiguous.

That said,  "she had" is more common, so you would probably guess it meant "she had" if you had to bet on it.

Even with the completion, it is still ambiguous: compare

> She'd come off her bike and hurt her knee just before the wedding started.  (had)

> She'd come off her bike and hurt her knee, if she wasn't careful. (would, to form conditional)

> She'd come off her bike and hurt her knee every summer. She'd always be covered in scratches and grazes by the time school started in September. (would, for past habit)

Comment: It's amazing acutally the listners or readers have to wait for the context that come later. I may stop the speaker and ask 'what contraction of she'd you meant 1. she had, 2. she would (conditional) 3. she would (past habit)' English is really amazing.

Comment: Not amazing at all, and totally normal in all natural languages.  Nothing is ever understood without context.  This is just as true in your language as it is in English. You just don't notice it because you are *just so good* at using the context.  But try writing a computer program to understand your native language, and you'll quickly realise just how much is context, shared understanding, common knowledge, pragmatic rather than semantic.